# Clear soup with snow globe flakes

Tags: soup, cauliflower

I've been searching for years to no avail for a clear cauliflower and blue cheese broth soup.

It looks like those Snow Globes, the one's you shake. The cauliflower snows in the dish each mouthful.

I presume it's cauliflower stalk broth with a vege stock, then baked florets are blended? Somehow with blue cheese.

Each time I try it isn't clear or when it is the cauliflower doesn't snow flake. The problem is if I blend it too fine it goes mushy and grating it creates slithers not flakes.

I think I need help, how do you do a snow flake soup dish?

Comment: If you post you current recipe, people here can help you modify it for the desired effect. As your question is right now, it's a recipe request which is off topic here,

Comment: Have you had this somewhere and want to emulate it, or is it an idea that you haven't perfected? Certainly sounds pretty :)

Comment: It was a cabin in the snow, she was a chef and wouldn't give me the recipe. It was so good. For years I've been looking at images for clear cauliflower soup and there's nothing. I thought maybe if I just described it's texture and content and the problem with the flakes part someone might be able to shed light. Its really delicious especially in cold climates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not difficult to produce a clear broth or consume.  Traditionally, an egg white raft is used to capture solids, and one can remove the clarified broth.  There are more modern techniques for liquid clarification, which can easily be found online. For example, agar can be employed to gel the broth.  The gel can be broken, and the clear liquid can be drained.  Remember though, clear does not mean without color.  So consider your soup ingredients as you think about the color of your final product.

For your soup, to me, the issue is the blue cheese, which will cloud your clear broth if added as pieces of blue cheese.  So, I would experiment with getting the blue cheese flavor into the broth.

Then, chop cauliflower in a food processor, as if you were making cauliflower "rice". The cauliflower would have to be raw, perhaps being cooked by the soup once added.  I am guessing these small pieces will sink in your bowl of clear soup.   Stir them up and it will "snow".

Comment: I've never made cheese rind stock, but it's a thing. I wonder if it would help here

Comment: Thanks, this gives me (a cooking novice) some pro tips to try and look into.